# How to disable autocommit in JDBC using clojure

Tags: jdbc, clojure, hive, database-partitioning

I want to use Clojure's JDBC interface to update an Hive database. In particular, I want to add partitions. The code would be like the following:

```
(jdbc/db-do-commands hive-db ["ALTER TABLE foo ADD PARTITION (year=2015, month=10, day=1, hour=1) LOCATION '/bar'"])
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: enabling autocommit is not supported
 at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.setAutoCommit (HiveConnection.java:1071)
    clojure.java.jdbc$db_transaction_STAR_.doInvoke (jdbc.clj:605)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    ...
```

As I'm aware, enabling autocommit in Hive's JDBC driver has [several](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6712) unresolved [issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6705) presently. Thus I want to disable autocommit. How is this done in `clojure.java.jdbc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following would be of assistance:

```
(let [con (db-find-connection db)]
   (.setAutoCommit con false))
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks - I found a workaround that resembles what you wrote.